# C# Graphic drawing and class instantiation

Tags: c#, winforms, class, drawing

Doing an exercise in a text book, but getting stuck. I need to draw a simple stick figure. However I need to create Face, Body class and call it in the main. Have done a Google search but can't seem to find the answer.

Below is an attempt to do this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class stickFace : Form
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics draw = e.Graphics;
        Pen black = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

        draw.DrawEllipse(black, 20, 20, 100, 100);

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}

public class stickBody : Form
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Draw Line codes goes here
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}

public class StickFigure : Form
{
    public StickFigure()
    {
        Size = new Size(500, 300);
        Text = "Stick Figure";
        BackColor = Color.White;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Call the stickface and stickBody Class
    }
}
```

How do I instantiate the StickFace and StickBody in the Main method? Or is my code complete wrong.

Comment: I think you should draw the components using GDI+ directly in OnPaint event, instead of inheriting from Form base.

Comment: It does not make much sense that the stickBody and stickFace classes inherit from the Form class because they are not Forms.

Comment: Instead, you can remove their inheritance from Form, and give them each Draw(Graphics g) methods, which will be called in the main Form's OnPaint method.

Answer (score 1):

#### Program.cs

```
 static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Application.Run(new stickFace());
    }
}
```

#### StickFace.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class stickFace : Form
{
     public stickFace()
    {
        new stickBody(this);
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics draw = e.Graphics;
        Pen black = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

        draw.DrawEllipse(black, 20, 20, 100, 100);

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

#### StickBody.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

 public class stickBody : Form
{
    public stickBody(stickFace obj)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {//lines of code.....

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```